# Remove Special Characters SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I am currently trying to run an SQL qeuery that strips out special characters and then adds a '1' in front to have all numbers correctly formatted. For what ever reason my `REPLACE` doesn't seem to work as I get return values like this `1(111) 111-` after the query completes. I am not getting any error and most of the numbers are in the correct fomrat just a random chunk that won't remove the characters. Here is my Query:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
CASE
 WHEN 
 LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Phone,'(',''),')',''),' ',''),'-',''),1) <> 1 THEN CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(Phone AS VARCHAR(10))
 ELSE Phone
END AS [Mobile Number],
id, PersonEmail, Phone, Name, Status__pc, User_Type__c, 'US' AS Locale
FROM Account_Salesforce
WHERE Status__pc = 'Active'
AND User_Type__c = 'Agent'
AND id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out! Here is the correct query:

```
SELECT scrubbed_phone, id, PersonEmail, Phone, Name, Status__pc, User_Type__c, Locale,
CASE
 WHEN 
 LEFT(scrubbed_phone,1) <> '1' THEN CONCAT('1',scrubbed_phone)
 ELSE scrubbed_phone
END AS [Mobile Number]
FROM
(
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Phone,'(',''),')',''),' ',''),'-','') AS scrubbed_phone,
id, PersonEmail, Phone, Name, Status__pc, User_Type__c, 'US' AS Locale
FROM Account_Salesforce
WHERE Status__pc = 'Active'
AND User_Type__c = 'Agent'
AND id IS NOT NULL) AS asdf
```